# Does Safari block Google tag manager?

Tags: safari, google-tag-manager

I have a regular tagmanager setup via adding script to . Looks like it is working OK on Chrome and on previous versions of Safari. But on Sonoma Safari browser just throws error "[Error] Cannot load [https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=....."](https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=.....%22).

It is not opened inside private mode so should not be related to advanced track protection

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, this is better suited for Super User or maybe Ask Different